# Texture streaming, where do I begin?

Tags: streaming, directx, textures

I'm interested in texture streaming in DirectX but google seems unhelpful. Maybe I just don't know the right questions to ask, can anyone point me on where to begin reading to learn about impleneting texture streaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could google for interesting tidbits, from [Insomniac Games](http://www.insomniacgames.com/tech/articles/1107/files/texture_streaming.pdf), notably.